# PHP regex exact match in multiple quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have this string (or similar):

```
<img data-src="useJS: 'true', useZoom: '#zoom1', image_big: '//cdn.example.com/big.jpg', image_orig: '//cdn.example.com/orig.gif', image_icon: '//thisDomain.com/images/icon.png'" />
...
```

I am using this regex in preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('/:\s?(\'[^"]+(.jpe?g|.gif|.png)\')/siU', $string, $match);
```

Matches are:

```
[1][0] => : ', useZoom: '#zoom1', image_big: '//cdn.example.com/big.jpg'
[1][1] => : '//cdn.example.com/big.jpg'
...
```

I like second match only and without comma in regex. I don't like first match, i need only image uri.

Comment: `preg_match_all` sets `$match` to a 2-dimensional array. How are you getting a flat array like that?

Comment: sorry, i'm update array result

Comment: That matches of the capture group will be in `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_match_all('/\'[^\']+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)\'/', $string, $match);
```

I changed `[^"]+` to `[^\']+`, so that this will just match strings between single quotes that end in one of the extensions. Also, you need to escape `.` before the extensions so it will be matched literally.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wZ7pH2/1)

Comment: first / missed and added and working and wonderful. thanks Barmar.